# php mysql wrapper class __destruct method fails to close database

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone explain why **mysql_close()** fails when called from a class destructor?  **mysql_error()** reports "Connection close failed."

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $link_id = 0;
    private $query_id = 0;

    public $error = "";
    public $errorNumber = 0;
    public $affectedRows = 0;

    public function __construct($server, $user, $pass, $database)
    {
        $this->link_id = @mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass, false);

        if (!$this->link_id)
        {
            $this->DisplayError("Could not connect to server: <b>$this->server</b>.");
            die(mysql_error());
        }

        if(!@mysql_select_db($database, $this->link_id))
        {
            $this->DisplayError("Could not open database: <b>$this->database</b>.");
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        if ($this->link_id)
        {
            if(!@mysql_close($this->link_id))
            {
                $this->DisplayError("Connection close failed.");
                die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you take the "@" off of it and let it actually log the problem instead of masking it?

Comment: Is `mysql_error()` reporting anything?

Comment: @dkamins I'm using a custom error handler.

Comment: mysql_error() reports "Connection close failed."

Comment: @Kevin: how custom error handler is related to `@`? Use custom and remove `@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to bug report [#27903](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27903), it appears some resources are already cleaned up by the time class destructors are called due to end of script execution.

In any case, as indicated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php)...

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.